# How to extract inline images from PDF using Apache Tika Server and save them as files?

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

Is there a way to do this?  I'm using the following headers in my PUT request to `http://localhost:9998/tika`

```
"Content-Type", "application/pdf"
"X-Tika-OCRLanguage", "eng"
"X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages", "true"
"X-Tika-PDFOcrStrategy", "no_ocr"
```

Will the response contain the images?  And if so, how do I save them?

Using Apache Tika server 1.26

Comment: Did you try [`/unpack`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-UnpackResource) ?

Answer (score 0):

the response will be string not the image(s)
the flag: PDFOcrStrategy tells the tika to use ocr (tesseract) or only try to extract the text from document without ocr - useful for native pdfs

the flag: PDFextractInlineImages tells the tika to ignore/include the embedded images

so when You have the scanned pdf you should use
"X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages", "true"
"X-Tika-PDFOcrStrategy", "ocr_only"
for native pdfs
"X-Tika-PDFextractInlineImages", "false"
"X-Tika-PDFOcrStrategy", "no_ocr"
but in both scenarios tika will return text

If you want to take the images from pdf document IMO you should use the pdf box, or similar library. The goal of tika is to return text from input